# Screen capture python 3.6.6 opencv and pillow not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

i am trying to do screen capture and it is only providing a black screen[image: Black screen]

here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2

while(True):
    printscreen_pil =  ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(781, 925, 814, 941))
    printscreen_numpy =   np.array(printscreen_pil.getdata(),dtype='uint8')\
    .reshape((printscreen_pil.size[1],printscreen_pil.size[0],3)) 
    cv2.imshow('window',printscreen_numpy)



    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

notice that bbox is (x1, y1, x2, y2), so (781, 925, 814, 941) is a narrow screen.

this is my example:

```
screen_w = 1920
screen_h = 1080 

while True:
    rgb = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, screen_w, screen_h)) #x1, y1, x2, y2
    rgb = np.array(rgb)

    cv2.imshow('window_frame', rgb)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: the channel num of ImageGrab.grab is 4, so "reshape((printscreen_pil.size[1],printscreen_pil.size[0],4))" should be work